# Estimated finish time app for treadmill running on iOS

Tags: ios

Does any know of any app that you can use on the treadmill to predict your estimated finish time for a given distance?

I imagine telling you're going to run 3 miles then set up a start speed and increase the speed in the app at the same time as the treadmill.

Comment: Those types of metrics are typically built in the actual device.  For example, the Concept2 erg can measure distance, times, etc.

Comment: My Concept2 erg does that and I love it, however I haven't seen that type of feature on many treadmills.  I know mine doesn't have it.   I was hoping that there was an app out there that would let me see that kind of information on my treadmill to help improve my times.